# Ruby method help required

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am reading Metaprogramming Ruby book, and there is method, which I cant understant:

```
def to_alphanumeric(s)
  s.gsub /[^\w\s]/, ''
end
```

I see there is Argument Variable (s), which is called lately and is converted to some weird expression?
What exactly can I do with this method, is he useful?

Following method works just fine:

```
def to_alphanumeric(s)
  s.gsub %r([aeiou]), '<\1>'
end

p = to_alphanumeric("hello")
p p
>> "h<>ll<>"
```

But if I upgrade method to class, simply calling the method + argv to_alphanumeric, no longer work:

```
class String 
  def to_alphanumeric(s)
    s.gsub %r([aeiou]), '<\1>'
  end
end
p = to_alphanumeric("hello")
p p
undefined method `to_alphanumeric' for String:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: For the class version: 

`class String
...
end

"hello".to_alphanumeric`

Answer (score 1):

Would it hurt to check the documentation?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub

> Returns a copy of str with the all occurrences of pattern substituted for the second argument.

The /[^\w\s]/ pattern means "everything that is not a word or whitespace"

Comment: Thank you, how do you exactly know what the given pattern means?
Link to resource will be nice!

Comment: To call this method, just use something like `to_alphanumeric(s)` => `hello`

Comment: The [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) class has a surprisingly large number of docs on it. But really, regular expressions are their own topic (Google should get you pretty far).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/), the regular expression `/[^\w\s]/` matches special characters like ^, /, or $ which are neither word characters (\w) or whitespace (\s). Therefore the function removes special characters like ^, / or $.

```
>> "^/$%hel1241lo".gsub /[^\w\s]/, ''
=> "hel1241lo"
```

call it simple like a function:

```
>> to_alphanumeric("U.S.A!")
=> "USA"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

I slightly updated my question, check it out please!